# Custom Glassfish realm

Tags: authorization, jaas, glassfish-4

I want to implement custom authorization in Glassfish 4. So I must implemented Realm class and LoginModule class extends AppservPasswordLoginModule. But I need to store in the principal class not only name of the principal but also id from database. How can I use my own implementation of Principal class?